# AzureDev Ops YAML Pipeline Trigger upon Pull-Request Completion

Tags: azure, azure-devops, triggers, azure-pipelines

Once all pull-request comments have been resolved the developer in our team is allowed to complete the PR (x). It is then merged back into the protected master.
It would be nice to trigger a pipeline (p), similar to a pre-merge-hook, that makes a specific build (for doxygen) and packs the created files together with the PR changes to the master.
To have that pipeline as a PR policy on master is no option, since it is triggered on every commit on that PR, which is too exhaustive for the agents.

Sure there is an easy way to do so? I simply cannot find any hint.

Master | PR

```
..
|
o
|\
| p
|  \
o   x
|   |
|   o
o  /
| /
|/
o
..
```

Comment: what about a build with CI trigger to the master?

Answer (score 0):

> AzureDev Ops YAML Pipeline Trigger upon Pull-Request Completion

I am afraid there is no such directly way to do this at this moment.

When we are in the PR process, Azure devops will synchronize the latest commit on the source branch to the PR by default and re-execute Build Validation.

As workaround, we can consider to remove the Build Validation in the PR policy on `master`, and enable the `CI trigger` for the `master` branch.

Besides, if you do not want the PR commits to break the master branch, we could create a `temp` branch and enable the `CI trigger` for this breach, if the build is successful, we could merge the `temp` branch to the master branch.

To disable the synchronize in the PR, you could submit this request to our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]